# How to generate a registration no. when user clicks on Submit button in PHP?

Tags: php, button

I want generate a registration no. of a user, but the registration no. should be:

- the first two digit no. should be year as - 15
- the second two digit no. should be month as - 06
- the third two should be characters which are already assigned as - SY
- the fourth should be a number as - 012
- The last number should be incremented when user clicks the button

So in this case my registration numbers would be "1506SY012", then "1506SY13", etc. How to generate it in PHP code?

Comment: You should specify what you have tried and where have you failed.

Comment: The registration no. is machine generated, right?

Comment: Please specify details on where the input comes from

Answer (score 0):

You need some place, where your users will be saved. For example: MySQL table. Create table with fields, for example: ID, SID, NAME, PASSWORD; ID field and index Primary Key, Auto increment. It gives you unique ID for every new user (just INT: 1, 2, 3, 4....).

Than, after you add new line to this table, you need to update it with:

```
$query = "insert into users values (NULL, '0', :name, :pass)";
$mysqli->query($query);
$lastId = $mysqli->insert_id;
$sid = date(dm, time()).'SY'.sprintf('%010s',$lastId);
$query = "update users u set u.sid = :sid where user_id = :id";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

And you'll get SID with needed value.